# How to change entry point to _tmain() for MFC Application

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How do I change the entry Point of my MFC Application ? Standard is `InitInstance()` of the class that `extends CWinApp`. But I need the entry Point at `_tmain()`. Will call `initInstance()` from there...

Comment: main() is the entrypoint for console mode apps.  Why are you trying to use a GUI class library in a console app?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? It will break how MFC gets initialized. `AfxGetApp` for example will not work. What you are trying which cannot be done in InitInstance ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set entry point of application by specifying linker option "/entry:myMain" or via pragma directive:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/entry:myMain")
```

Answer (score 0):

See the official [/Entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx) documentation for VC++ 2010 for how to set it and what the defaults are. Note that `main()` and `InitInstance()` may be the entry point for your code but it not necessarily the original entry point for the program. For example, trace into a MFC program and you'll see a large amount of initialization code that you probably don't want to skip.